# Blogger widget works only for current month

Tags: xml, ajax, markup, blogger

I'm trying to make my custom Blogger theme, so I have to deal with their data syntax (all these "b" namespaces, etc.)

Everything went good until I came to Archive widget. I have next construction:

```
<b:section id='BlogArchive'>
    <b:widget id='BlogArchive1' locked='true' title='Blog Archive' type='BlogArchive'>
        <b:includable id='main'>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" style="display: block; position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 180px;">
                <b:include data='data' name='interval'/>
            </ul>
        </b:includable>
        <b:includable id='interval' var='intervalData'>
            <b:loop values='data:intervalData' var='i'>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">   
                    <a tabindex="-1" expr:href='data:i.url'><data:i.name/> (<data:i.post-count/>)</a>
                    <b:if cond='data:i.data'>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <b:include data='i.data' name='interval'/>
                        </ul>
                    </b:if>
                    <b:if cond='data:i.posts'>
                        <b:include data='i.posts' name='posts'/>
                    </b:if>
                </li>
            </b:loop>
        </b:includable>
        <b:includable id='posts' var='posts'>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <b:loop values='data:posts' var='i'>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" expr:href='data:i.url'><data:i.title/></a></li>
                </b:loop>
            </ul>
        </b:includable>
    </b:widget>
</b:section>
```

And the problem is that this snippet works only for current month: all previous months seems to be empty (with no posts listed in drop-down list).

I've checked the original widget and recognized that by default server returns only current month's posts and then it uses AJAX to load older months' posts (when expanding the list).

So the question is: how to edit my snippet to make it load titles for all chronological existing of a blog? Maybe I should use some JavaScript or AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

What ill suggest you is remove the following code

```
<b:widget id='BlogArchive1' locked='true' title='Blog Archive' type='BlogArchive'>
        <b:includable id='main'>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" style="display: block; position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 180px;">
                <b:include data='data' name='interval'/>
            </ul>
        </b:includable>
        <b:includable id='interval' var='intervalData'>
            <b:loop values='data:intervalData' var='i'>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">   
                    <a tabindex="-1" expr:href='data:i.url'><data:i.name/> (<data:i.post-count/>)</a>
                    <b:if cond='data:i.data'>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <b:include data='i.data' name='interval'/>
                        </ul>
                    </b:if>
                    <b:if cond='data:i.posts'>
                        <b:include data='i.posts' name='posts'/>
                    </b:if>
                </li>
            </b:loop>
        </b:includable>
        <b:includable id='posts' var='posts'>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <b:loop values='data:posts' var='i'>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" expr:href='data:i.url'><data:i.title/></a></li>
                </b:loop>
            </ul>
        </b:includable>
    </b:widget>
```

and then save your template. while saving, it will ask you if to delete widget. click on delete widget and then again goto your layouts tab and add a new widget for archive. this must work

Include your blog URL so that i can check your blog

Regards,
Gireesh - [www.CoreBlogging.in](http://www.CoreBlogging.in)